# Adding inputed value to CurrentTime

Tags: cobol

I'm trying to make a Computer Cafe System and my problem is how do I add the input value in number of hours to the current time for example time now is 11.30 and the input value is 5 so the End Time will be 4:30

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. Example.
   AUTHOR. Lee Martin Flores.

   DATA DIVISION.

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 MachineNo PIC 99 VALUE ZEROS.

   01 Hours PIC 99 VALUE ZEROS.

   01 Result PIC 99 VALUE ZEROS.

   01 Charge PIC 99 VALUE 10.

   01 EndTime PIC 9999 VALUE ZEROS.

   01 CurrentTime.
      02 CurrentHour PIC 99.
      02 CurrentMinute PIC 99.
      02 FILLER PIC 9(4).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
        DISPLAY "Enter Machine No : ".
        Accept MachineNo.
        DISPLAY "How Many Hours: ".
        Accept Hours.
        MULTIPLY Hours BY Charge GIVING Result.
        DISPLAY "Enter Current Time : ".
        ACCEPT CurrentTime FROM TIME.
        ADD CurrentTime TO Hours GIVING EndTime.


        DISPLAY "Machine No : ", MachineNo.
        DISPLAY "The Time is " CurrentHour ":" CurrentMinute.
        DISPLAY "Number of Hours : ", Hours.
        DISPLAY "Charge Per Hour:  ", Charge.
        DISPLAY "Total Charge/Amount: ", Result.
        DISPLAY "End Time is : ", EndTime

            STOP RUN.
```

I'm having problems when I realcob it:
31 E Expected numeric item; found 'CurrentTime'
and is the code correct for displaying the end time?

Comment: CurrentTime is not a numeric data-item, it is a group-item, which is automatically alpha-numeric so you can't do calculations with it. You should have typed CurrentHour. You also need to check for "running over midnight". Your EndTime is two large (you don't need more than two digits) and doesn't need an initial value as it is always receives data before you reference it.

Comment: On the other hand, you need 2 more digits in your PICTURE for `Result`.  With your current code, when `Hours` is 15 (for example) and `Charge` is 25, `Result` will be 75, not 375.